# Resolving query type with promise in bucklescript

Tags: graphql, reason, bucklescript

I've got this query im trying to test with with the reason graphql_ppx library. [code gist](https://gist.github.com/idkjs/6e3fa8b163f2f6e5e33b8e5f4bac46a3)

This is a screenshot of the editor type annotations:
[image]

Using the [@mhallin/graphql_ppx](https://github.com/mhallin/graphql_ppx) library, i've got the following query set up:

```
    module FilmQuery = [%graphql
  {|
    {
      allFilms {
        films {
          id
          title
          releaseDate
        }
      }
    }
|}
];

exception Graphql_error(string);

/* Construct a "packaged" query; FilmQuery takes no arguments: */
let filmQuery = FilmQuery.make();

/* Send this query string to the server */
let query = filmQuery##query // type string
```

I get an the following error when i send the query to the server it returns the following error.

```
{ errors: [ { message: 'Must provide query string.' } ] }
```

But if you Js.log(query) you see its being constructed [which works on https://swapi.apis.guru](http://swapi.apis.guru/?operationName=null&query=%7B%0A%20%20allFilms%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20films%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20releaseDate%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

```
query films($first: Int)  {
  allFilms(first: $first)  {
   films  {
     id  
     title  
     releaseDate  
   }
  }
}
```

If you Js.log(filmQuery) you get:

```
{ query: 'query   {\nallFilms  {\nfilms  {\nid  \ntitle  \nreleaseDate  \n}\n}\n}',
```

variables: null,
  parse: [Function: parse] }

If your run the same query in Altair and you check the query that was sent in the devtools network tab you see:

```
{"query":"    query films($first: Int) {\n      allFilms(first: $first) {\n        films {\n          id\n          title\n          releaseDate\n        }\n      }\n    }\n","variables":{}}
```

The editor is provided this type error:
"- error
[bucklescript]
This has type:
  string
But somewhere wanted:
  Js.t({.. query : string, variables : Js.Json.t })
string"

How do I get this promise/unit type resolved? Thank you.

So the new question is: Why isn't the sendQuery() function recognizing the `filmQuery##parse` key?

Comment: Looks like you may want to be passing `filmQuery` into `sendQuery` instead of the `query` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sendQuery` method is expecting a type in the shape of what is returned from `FilmQuery.make()`, but you are passing it just the `query` property, which is a `string`.

You can fix this by passing `filmQuery` as into `sendQuery` instead of just the `query` property from `filmQuery` that is referenced by the `query` variable.